# how to use constant in cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Hello Friends This is my Function ...

**bootstrap.php**

```
$support_email = 'addon.akbar@gmail.com';
define('SUPPORT_EMAIL', $support_email);
```

**testcontroller.php**

```
public function testcron(){

        $email = new Email('default');
        $email->from(['aon.akbarali@gmail.com' => 'My Site'])
            ->to('aon.ashish@gmail.com')
            ->subject('About')
            ->send('My message');
    }
```

when I run this function it says "already use constant". Actually i don't know how can i use this constant.. Can anyone Tell me ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use constant in core php like this.

```
define('SUPPORT_EMAIL', $support_email); 
echo SUPPORT_EMAIL;
```

In cakephp 3.x you can use constant like this.

**In config/Bootstrap.php**

```
$support_email = 'addon.akbar@gmail.com';
Configure::write('SUPPORT_EMAIL', $support_email);
```

**In controller**

```
use Cake\Core\Configure; 

public function testcron(){

    $support_email = Configure::read('SUPPORT_EMAIL');
 }
```

**In view file**

```
<?php use Cake\Core\Configure; 
$support_email = Configure::read('SUPPORT_EMAIL');
?>
```

Comment: if i have a number of constants where should i define them instead of bootstrap ?

Comment: @KashishAgarwal you can write all the constants in a single file and can include on bootstrap.php

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because this contant is already defined somewhere. Either you can change the constant name or do the following

```
if (!defined('SUPPORT_EMAIL')) {
    $support_email = 'addon.akbar@gmail.com';
    define('SUPPORT_EMAIL', $support_email);
}
```

This will create constant only if it does not exist.

Comment: You can directly write SUPPORT_EMAIL anywhere you want to use it's value.